# Eigenvalues of a generalized Gram matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Let $P \in \rm{GL}_N(\mathbb{C})$. Call the columns of $P$  $|R_i\rangle$ and the rows of $P^{-1}$  $\langle L_i|$, so that
$$
\langle L_i | R_j \rangle = \delta_{i,j}.
$$ 
And define the matrix $G$ by 
$$
G_{i,j} = \langle R_i | R_j \rangle \langle L_j | L_i \rangle.
$$
One can prove that $G$ is hermitian and positive-definite, and also that for any $i$,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^N G_{i,j} = 1,
$$
which implies that $1 \in \rm{Spec}(G)$. I would like to know whether $1$ is always the **smallest** eigenvalue. It seems to be the case but I have no proof of this fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in conventional mathematical notation this would be the Hadamard product $X \circ X^{-T}$ (I think it's a pure transpose and not a conjugate transpose, but please double-check this) with the positive definite matrix $X = P^*P$. So this assertion is a consequence of Theorem 5.4.3 in Horn and Johnson's *Topics in Matrix Analysis*:

> Let $A \in M_n$ be positive definite. Then
>
> (a) $\lambda_{\min}(A \circ A^{-1}) \geq 1$
>
> (b) $\lambda_{\min}(A \circ A^{-T}) = 1$

Comment: This is exactly the reference I needed. Thanks !